# Codeigniter ajax check email availability

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have been trying check email availibity using ajax and jquery script as follows,

my controller:

```
$get_result = $this->user->check_email_availablity();      
        if($get_result == FALSE ) {  
            $validate['message'] = '<p>Email is not available.</p>';
        } else  { 
            $validate['message'] = '<p>Email is available.</p>';
        }            
        $this->load->view('user/signup', $validate);
```

my model:

```
function check_email_availablity()  {
        $email = $this->input->post('u_email');
        $query = $this->db->query('SELECT u_email FROM tbl_users where u_email = "'.$email.'"');      
        if($query->num_rows() === 1) {   
            return FALSE;
        } else {
            return TRUE; 
        }
    }
```

my js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {     
        /// make loader hidden in start     
        $('#Loading').hide();            
        $('#email').blur(function(){   
        var a = $("#email").val();   
        var filter = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]+.[a-z]{2,4}$/;        
        // check if email is valid   
        if(filter.test(a)){                 
         // show loader     
         $('#Loading').show();    
         $.post("<?php echo base_url()?>main/signup", {     
         email: $('#email').val()    
        },
        function(response){                         
         //#emailInfo is a span which will show you message     
         $('#Loading').hide();     
         setTimeout("finishAjax('Loading', '"+escape(response)+"')", 400);    
        });    
        return false;   
       } 
       }); 
       function finishAjax(id, response){   
        $('#'+id).html(unescape(response));   
        $('#'+id).fadeIn(); 
       }
    });
```

my view:

```
 <?php echo form_input('u_email', set_value('u_email'), 'class="form-control" id="email"'); ?>
                <span id="Loading"><?php echo $message; ?></span>
```

My problem is model always returns TRUE and shows 'email is available' message, how do I check the email availability live

Comment: yeah I checked that way too and `>0` still issue is remaining

Comment: echo $query->num_rows() and check the result .. is its return 1 ?

Comment: No its return 0 after clicking submit button only return 1

Comment: so $query->num_rows() give value 0 always ?

Comment: no when form is submitted with existing email it shows 1

Comment: ok if($query->num_rows()) {  } try like this

Comment: yeah still the same, I think that problem comes because of JavaScript issue, its not validating real time and  wait for click submit button to execute script

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84422/discussion-between-user1048123-and-sahan-perera).

Answer (score 1):

In your model change the if condition in query row:

```
function check_email_availablity()  {
        $email = $this->input->post('u_email');
        $query = $this->db->query('SELECT u_email FROM tbl_users where u_email = "'.$email.'"');      
        if($query->num_rows() > 0) {   
            return FALSE;
        } else {
            return TRUE; 
        }
    }
```

And in your controller:

```
       $get_result = $this->user->check_email_availablity();      
        if(!$get_result) //if email already exist in your database
        {  
            $validate['message'] = '<p>Email is not available.</p>';
        } else  { 
            $validate['message'] = '<p>Email is available.</p>';
        }            
        $this->load->view('user/signup', $validate);
```

Comment: did you check if the email really exists in your database?

Comment: yeah i checked with existing emails and non existing ones